# What tense is "would have been"?

Tags: verbs, tenses, conditionals, modal-verbs, perfect-aspect

This is used in Conditional Type 3. But no one knows what tense this is...

Comment: *Perfect continuous conditional tense*?

Comment: The prevailing school of thought on ELU seems to be that English has only two tenses (present simple: I walk; past simple: I walked) and a host of _constructions_ employed to show time frame; irrealis, perfective, repeated scenarios etc.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth When English is said to have only two tenses, are the two tenses the present simple and the past simple? If so, is _I was sleeping_ a non-tensed clause?

Comment: @JK2 (b) No; that's reserved for pure participial / infinitival usages. (a) Here, 'was' is in the past simple, of course, though the auxiliary is used in a **_construction_** one probably still uses the traditional label 'past continuous' for. The semantics (in the past; durative state) is of course invariant; it's just how the word 'tense' is 'stipulating-defined'. The modern uses need there to be an inflecting form of the simplex verb (at least for the 'most inflecting' verb/s): am/are/is...; was/were)..

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Are you talking about grammatical tenses or semantic tenses?

Comment: @CJDennis Grammatical Tenses

Comment: @DavidChiu That was a rhetorical question. English verbs have only a present and past form (jump(s)/jumped). Grammar adds more: (am/are/is jumping, have/has jumped, will jump, etc.). Semantics adds even more: (I jump (simple present), I jump (habitual), etc.).

Comment: @CJ Dennis Grammatical tenses / semantic tenses as defined by which school?

Answer (score 3):

In English, tense of a finite clause is always marked on the first verb of the finite clause, and is either 'present' or 'past'. (A non-finite clause doesn't have any tense.)

In your example, the first verb *would* is the only finite verb--and the only tensed verb--and is in the past tense. Therefore, *would have been* is in the past tense.

Answer (score -2):

the verb group 'would have been' is

present (have), finite, perfect (been), non-progressive, modal (would), positive, non-contrastive

which in so-called 3rd conditionals expresses past irrealis, eg,

Had you been there, it *would have been* nice.